# Copy window between multiple Spaces in Mission Control?

Tags: macos, mission-control

When I open Mission Control, I see that I can drag windows between Spaces and that moves the window to that Space.

What I want is to *copy* the window instance so I can interact with it on any of the Spaces.

This is very common functionality for virtual desktop programs on Windows (like Dexpot), where for example I can have my email program always available as I move around to different desktops. I'd like to do this same thing with Mission Control.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get one window of an app to follow you to all Spaces - but you can, if you have shortcut keys setup to swap Spaces, grab the menu bar of the required window, hit the shortcut & 'take it with you' to the new Space.

If you don't have it set up already, System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts…
[image]

One thing to note - if you do that with Finder windows, it can break the 'click desktop to go back to Space 1' functionality, til you relaunch the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do this in Mission Control, but you can get the same result by right-clicking the application icon in the Dock and assigning the application to all desktops.

Comment: That appears to be whole applications, though... I'm looking for a way to do individual windows. Like, I don't want ALL Safari windows to be on all spaces, just ONE window.